# C++11 std::list iterator invalidation after splicing

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, stl, iterator

I'm trying to understand how `std::list` iterators are affected after splice operations in C++11. Here is a small example that does not behave as I expect:

```cpp
std::list<int> A({1, 2, 3});
std::list<int> B;
auto p = A.begin(), q = A.end();
auto p_copy = p, q_copy = q;

// True:
std::cout << "p == A.begin()? " << (p == A.begin()) << std::endl;
// True:
std::cout << "p_copy == A.begin()? " << (p_copy == A.begin()) << std::endl;

B.splice(B.end(), A, p, q);

// True:
std::cout << "p == B.begin()? " << (p == B.begin()) << std::endl;
// False, but I don't understand why:
std::cout << "p_copy == A.begin()? " << (p_copy == A.begin()) << std::endl;
// True, but I don't understand why either:
std::cout << "p_copy == B.begin()? " << (p_copy == B.begin()) << std::endl;
```

In this example, I don't understand why the `p_copy` iterator no longer points to `A.begin()` after the splice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` iterators point to elements. By splicing a range of elements, you've changed which container those iterators point into. The element is no longer an element of `A`; it is an element of `B`. Iterators are preserved across `splice`ing, so `p` and `p_copy` will still point to those elements.

They're just iterators into different containers now.

Comment: I see... So after the splice, `q != B.end()` because the `end` iterator does not point at an element, it points at one past the last element. Instead, after the splice `q == A.end()`. Is this correct?

Comment: @proc-self-maps `q == A.end()` because the end of the range passed to `splice` is not moved.  Even if `q` pointed to an element of `A`, it would not be moved, because the end iterator of a range represents the first element not within that range.

Comment: @proc-self-maps: "*Instead, after the splice q == A.end(). Is this correct?*" No, it's not. It may be true, but after splicing that range, `A.end()` could be a completely different value (particularly since `A` is empty after the splice). If `q` were an actual element, then `q` would still be an iterator into `A`. But since it's the end iterator, things work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally because this is the defined behavior of [`list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice):

> No iterators or references become invalidated, the iterators to moved elements remain valid, but now refer into `*this`, not into other.